# Use python `regex` to get the string in parentheses

Tags: python, regex, string, findall

I want to get the string within parentheses from a string with complex parentheses.

Also, parentheses in strings within parentheses are correctly paired.

For example for the input `abc[a[12] + b[1] * (12 + 13)] = efg[14]`,

If the request comes in like this, `abc[<Answer string>]`

In this case `<Answer string>` is neither `a[12`, nor `a[12] + b[1`, nor `a[12] + b[1] * (12 + 13)] = efg[14` ,  but `a[12] + b[1] * (12 + 13)` .

---

This question was asked to modify the python code.
I added an example I used.

### input

`self._vars[os.path.basename(b)[:-4]] = nn.Parameter(v, requires_grad=requires_grad)`

### output

`setattr(self, os.path.basename(b)[:-4], nn.Parameter(v, requires_grad=requires_grad))`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
import re
string = 'abc[a[12] + b[1] * (12 + 13)]'

match = re.findall('\[(.+)\]', string)
print(match[0])
```

Output:

```
a[12] + b[1] * (12 + 13)
```

Here, `\[(.+)\]` is matching everything between the outer square brackets.

**EDIT:**

To match `a[12] + b[1] * (12 + 13)` from the input `abc[a[12] + b[1] * (12 + 13)] = efg[14]`, you can instead use the regex `\[(.+)\] =` or `\[(.+)\]`  (note the space at the end of the latter).

Comment: sorry, I change the example. from `abc[a[12] + b[1] * (12 + 13)]` to `abc[a[12] + b[1] * (12 + 13)] = efg[14]`

This question needs to extract the string from the starting parenthesis until the matching parenthesis is met.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to extract everything within the square brackets of the pattern "blah[ ... ] = blah", so you can try the following regex.

The group including parenthesis (.+) matches any number of characters once or more times. The parenthesis control which parts of the string are returned after a match

```
import re
input = 'abc[a[12] + b[1] * (12 + 13)] = efg[14]'

output = re.findall('\[(.+)\] \=', input)
for e in output:    #output is a list
    print(e)
```

Output:

```
a[12] + b[1] * (12 + 13)
```

Comment: hi @tsp  is my suggestion able to answer your question?